# Is there a way to fire an e-mail workflow without saving a record first?

Tags: workflow, email-template, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a business case where 1.) someone takes a phone call 2) creates a case 
3) ends call and continues researching before saving the case finally

a user could have multiple case tabs open before saving any

We have implemented a workflow where after a case is created it will send an email to the person who called 30 minutes later to ask to submit a survey

My business users are asking if there is a way to do this, but without saving the record first I don't know how that would happen? Is this a situation where a visual flow would help to fire off an email before the record is saved?

Comment: That solution is a non-starter. Workflows of any sort can only trigger when a record is saved. You could maybe create a custom Visualforce page, Lightning component, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow rules are triggered only after Insert/Update DMl OPerations. Hence you cannot send out emails using workflow rules without saving the record first.

You can create a VF Page/Lightning Page to send out emails using Apex without saving the record first.

[send emails through Apex](http://%20Search%20on%20Salesforce%E2%80%A6%20Log%20in%20Sign%20up%20By%20using%20our%20site,%20you%20acknowledge%20that%20you%20have%20read%20and%20understand%20our%20Cookie%20Policy,%20Privacy%20Policy,%20and%20our%20Terms%20of%20Service.%20%20Confirm%20your%20new%20account%20You%20are%20about%20to%20create%20a%20new%20account%20on%20Salesforce%20Stack%20Exchange%20using%20a%20login%20from%20%20Google%20(dev.aggarwal99@gmail.com)%20%20We%20will%20automatically%20link%20this%20account%20with%20your%20accounts%20on%20other%20Stack%20Exchange%20sites.%20%20Confirm%20new%20account%20Cancel%20By%20clicking%20%E2%80%9CConfirm%20new%20account%E2%80%9D,%20you%20agree%20to%20our%20terms%20of%20service,%20privacy%20policy%20and%20cookie%20policy)